# User gets logged out in SalesforceMobileSDK for ios connected app

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, ios

I have an app based on ReactNativeTemplate.  Token is valid until revoked.  However since IOS 15 release users are logged out after 15 minutes of inactivity (Regardless of session settings which should not matter anyway).  Token expiration is handled within the react native app when calls are made to the server and renewed using refresh token.  But the js code is never reached and the user is being logged out directly after 15 minutes (assuming the token expired but can't confirm).  Has anyone experienced this?  This worked fine on all other ios versions. I tested on clean template with latest version and experience the same issue so my original code should not be the issue.